# Magento 2 - Backend Catalog - Product Table Top Not Displaying Correctly

Tags: magento-2.1

Php 7.0
Magento 2.1.0
Apache 2.4.6
DB: Maria DB
I'm having an issue with the top row of the table used in the backend, where it has ID, Thumbnail, Name, Type, Attribute etc etc... and allows you so sort ascending/descending.
It was working perfectly fine yesterday, no changes had been done and today it looks like this:
[image]

Edit 1:
I also now have noticed its also on the Customer list:
[image]

Its also on other pages such as viewing static blocks etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out the answer, it was Google's PageSpeed Insights apache optimizations, I needed to add the following to Pagespeed's config file to correct the backend issues.

> ModPagespeedDisallow https://www.EXAMPLE.co.uk/admin/
>
>   *ModPagespeedDisallow http://www.EXAMPLE.co.uk/admin/*
>   ModPagespeedDisallow https://www.EXAMPLE.co.uk/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/
>
>   *ModPagespeedDisallow http://www.EXAMPLE.co.uk/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/*

This excludes the backend from its optimizations.

Please note, you will need to change EXAMPLE.co.uk to your domain and /admin/ to whatever your custom admin panel url is.

All of those need a asterisk (*) after each, but for some reason its not displaying on here.